# create a folder in google drive and uploading files to it

Tags: python, google-drive-api

How I can create a folder inside the google drive and upload files into that  folder? (in python)

I have tried with the google tutorials but it is giving me errors

creating a folder, not working giving me errors like 'drive_service not defined'

```
file_metadata = {
    'title': 'Files',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
}
file = drive_service.files().insert(body=file_metadata,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'Folder ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```

Used this code for uploading a file and it is working, how I can modify it for uploading a file into a folder if that exists, if not create one and upload.

```
import json
import requests
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer Token"}

para = {
    "name": "index.jpeg",

}
files = {
    'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
    'file': open("./index.jpeg", "rb")
}
r = requests.post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
    headers=headers,
    files=files
)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Please share an example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Posted the code sample that I have tried for creating a folder. It is giving me drive_service not defined error

Comment: You seem to be missing the building of the `drive_service`, e.g. `drive_service = apiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v2', http=<auth>)`

Comment: Is it possible to create the folder simply by using the access token only?

Comment: @kkr You want to upload a file to the specific folder using Drive API v3. If my understanding is correct, how about modifying ``para`` to ``para = {"name": "index.jpeg", "parents": ["### folderId ###"]}``? This modification supposes that your current script works. You van see the document at [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create).

Comment: @Tanaike how will I get the folder ID ?

Comment: @kkr I apologize for my incomplete comment. In order to retrieve the folder ID, how about using [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)? Also you can retrieve manually from Google Drive like ``https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/### folderId ###``.

Comment: sorry for asking again and again, how can I create folder if it doesn't exist

Comment: @kkr Yes. You can create new folder using [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create). At that time, please set the mimeType (``application/vnd.google-apps.folder``) of folder.

Comment: Thankyou so muchh @Tanaike

Comment: [import requests
access_token = "TOKEN"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token}
r = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files', headers=headers)
print(r.text)]

Where I can add the mimeType??@Tanaike

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what I think you're looking for (its a self-contained example, but I think you can modify it to your own existing code):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'

def main():

    # Access the Drive service
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))


    # Check if folder exists (simply matching by name)
    folder_name = "Photos"

    folder_id = None
    query = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false and name='" + folder_name + "'"
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=1, q=query, fields="files(id, name)").execute()
    folders = results.get('files', [])

    if folders:
        folder_id = folders[0]['id']

    # If folder not found, then create it.
    else:
        file_metadata = {
            'name': folder_name,
            'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
        }
        folder_file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                            fields='id').execute()

        folder_id = folder_file.get('id')


    # Add file to folder.
    file_metadata = {
        'name': 'photo.png',
        'parents': [folder_id]
    }
    media = MediaFileUpload('photo.png',
                            mimetype='image/png',
                            resumable=True)

    image_file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                              media_body=media,
                                              fields='id').execute()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Nice.
NB there are 2 bugs in your code. the `q=` should include `trashed=false` and you need to iterate the `files().list` until `nextPageToken` is null
As an optimisation, you should include 'name=folder_name` in the q so you only fetch matching folders. Your code will fetch all folders (well up to the first 100)

Comment: @pinoyyid Thanks so much, I was rushing a bit to get the answer up, but will modify it now per your suggestions!

Comment: @pinoyyid Since they are only matching the folder by name, with your 'name=folder_name' fix, I just took the first folder with that name.

Comment: So far so good. But what if the first result from files.list is empty and the nextPageTokenis is set to indicate that more pages follow?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. I believe pages are filled up in order.

Comment: no they aren't. The docs specifically state that pages can be sparse or even empty

Comment: Hmm I didn't know. I'm curious as to how/why that would be the case

Comment: Google Drive is massively distributed. It could take so long to fill a page that the http get times out. Therefore GDrive provides partial results, and sets the nextPageToken to indicate that there are more results available.